# How to add product price to session with AJAX Magento 2

Tags: magento2, price, ajax

How to add the product **price** to session **with AJAX** Magento 2.
Please give me an example of the custom module of this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have answered your previous question([Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/348653/91109)) where you asked how to save custom data into the session, please use those same controllers from it, now, please look below code -

```
public function execute()
{
$productPrice = "200";
$productId = "5762413";
$customerSession = $this->session->getData();
$this->session->setProductId($productId);
$this->session->setProductPrice($productPrice);
$data = $this->session->getData();
$redirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
$params = $this->request->getParams();
return $redirect->setPath('cms/custom/index');
}
```